# VScode attach to unprepared remote python process?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

I have a Python process running on a raspberry pi processor elsewhere in my house. It has been working smoothly enough, long enough, that I quit running it in debug mode and just ran it the normal way, directly from the raspberry pi. I did not use debugpy.  Now it shows evidence of a bug. I'd like to attach from my development computer, have a debugging session, and see what's going on in there. Is this possible?

Even if not, if I had started it with debugpy, I'd like to know for future reference: what setup steps would it take?

Comment: a process that is not aware of a possible debugger connection will not spontaneous switch to a debug mode, debug mode is slow

Answer (score 1):

1. Install debugpy package by command `pip install debugpy` in your terminal.
2. You need to modify your Python script to start `debugpy` at the beginning.

   ```py
   import debugpy
   debugpy.listen(('the IP address of your Raspberry Pi', 5678))
   debugpy.wait_for_client()
   ```
3. Open your `launch.json` and add the following codes:

   ```json
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
               "type": "python",
               "request": "attach",
               "connect": {
                   "host": "ip_of_your_raspberry_pi",
                   "port": 5678
               },
               "pathMappings": [
                   {
                       "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                       "remoteRoot": "."
                   }
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
4. To start the debugging session, select `Python: Remote Attach` and click on the Start Debugging button (or press `F5`).

[image]